# Setting Up Delegation with Xcode 6 and OBJ C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm officially stuck. I am trying to send data (NSString) from one view controller to another. I believe I have everything set properly, but it doesn't work. I made a sample app to test. If anyone can look at and advise, I will really appreciate it.

Sample app has 2 view controllers. VC1 has a simple UITextView. VC2 has a UITextField. By pressing a button on VC1, VC2 appears modally. A user can then input data into VC2, and when pressing the close button, the data should fill the text view in VC1. Problem is this doesn't work.

Thanks for looking at.

VC1.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ViewController2Delegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *mainTextView;

@end
```

VC1.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)dataForMainViewSet:(ViewController2 *)sender dataToSet:(id)data {
    self.mainTextView.text = data;
}
@end
```

VC2.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController2;

@protocol ViewController2Delegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)dataForMainViewSet:(ViewController2 *)sender dataToSet:(id)data;
@end

@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <ViewController2Delegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)closeVC2;
@end
```

VC2.m

```
#import "ViewController2.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController2 () <UITextFieldDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController2

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.textField.delegate = self;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

- (IBAction)closeVC2 {
    [self.delegate dataForMainViewSet:self
                            dataToSet:self.textField.text];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

Comment: self.delegate in closeVC2 is not set, is it?

Comment: @Thorsten: Not apparently.  Which also points out that there could be a whole bunch of nil-checking done here.  NSParameterAssert() is handy...

Comment: What do you mean by "this doesn't work"? are you getting an error?

Comment: The  data from VC2 never gets to VC1. How do I set self.delegate? Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: In your VC1, before presenting VC2, set vc2.delegate to self (this should be VC1 instance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the comments and help. @Kilogen9 you jarred my memory and I remembered what I was missing.

I embed VC2 in a Navigation Controller. And then in VC1 I added a prepareForSegue and there prior to segue, I set VC2.delegate to self.

I was away from coding for almost a year and have been sitting here looking at my code in my real project for at least a week, trying to figure out what step I was forgetting. Once again, the Stack Overflow community helped.

Thanks!